# How to disable tls 1.0 & 1.1 of a route in OpenShift Online Pro

Tags: apache, routes, ssl-certificate, openshift, tls1.2

I am using OpenShift Online Pro account , I deployed a web application using apache httpd2.4 server and I created a route with domain I purchased from AWS.

Then I add SSL certificates using letsencrypt , now when I test this router I can see tls 1.0 & 1.1 are deprecated and some list of weak ciphers and I want to remove them from this router.

How can I disable this 2 versions and remove weak Ciphers ?

Any help could be appreaciated!

Answer (score 0):

In OpenShift, TLS ciphers can only be enabled / disabled on a Router basis ([see documentation](https://docs.openshift.com/container-platform/3.11/install_config/router/default_haproxy_router.html#bind-ciphers)). This means for OpenShift Online this is most likely not possible, although I would recommend to ask Support about it.

A workaround would be to use a "passthrough" Route and to terminate TLS in your container. That way you can control what TLS versions your application  / webserver is serving.

Comment: I am using apache server so I changed deployment files to disable those version as per Apache document but it didn't show any effect. May be I need to connect to customer support.Thanks for your advise.